# Solving a Binary Puzzle

Tags: c++

A while ago I started solving [Binary Puzzle](http://www.binarypuzzle.com)s (also known as "binero"). Not having done much C++ in my life, although it feels like I have a pretty good understanding of C++ in general, I figured it was time to do some C++!

The rules for a Binary Puzzle are:

- The entire grid should be filled up with 1's and 0's.
- There cannot be more than two 1's and 0's consecutively together.
- There are an equal amount of 1's and 0's in each row and each column.
- All columns are unique and all rows are unique.

This code is able to solve all Easy and Medium puzzles on [binarypuzzle.com](http://binarypuzzle.com). I realized later that I could solve these kinds of puzzles much easier using some already existing Java code I have written, which will be shown in an upcoming question. [to-be-continued](/questions/tagged/to-be-continued)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class BineroTile {
public:
    BineroTile() {
        clear();
    }

    bool zero;
    bool one;

    void clear() {
        zero = true;
        one = true;
    }

    bool hasValue() {
        return zero ^ one;
    }

    int getValue() {
        if (!hasValue()) {
            return -1;
        }
        return one ? 1 : 0;
    }

    void set(int value) {
        zero = value == 0;
        one = value == 1;
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const BineroTile& dt);

    void operator=(const int &value) {
        set(value);
    }

    bool operator == (const BineroTile &other) const {
        if (this->zero && this->one) {
            return false;
        }
        return (this->zero == other.zero) && (this->one == other.one);
    }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const BineroTile &m) { 
    if (m.one && m.zero) {
        return os << "_";
    }
    if (!m.one && !m.zero) {
        return os << "#";
    }
    return os << (m.one ? "1" : "0");
}

class BineroMatch {
    std::vector<BineroTile*> tiles;
    int unknown;

public:
    BineroMatch(std::vector<BineroTile*> tiles) : tiles(tiles) {
    }

    bool scan() {
        bool simplified = false;
        unsigned int zeros = 0;
        unsigned int ones = 0;
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {
            BineroTile* current = tiles[i];

            if (current->getValue() == 0) {
                zeros++;
            }
            if (current->getValue() == 1) {
                ones++;
            }

            if (i < tiles.size() - 1) {
                BineroTile* next = tiles[i + 1];

                // Find Pairs - compare the current value with the next value
                if (*current == *next) {

                    int value = 1 - current->getValue();

                    if (i > 0) {
                        BineroTile* before = tiles[i - 1];
                        simplified |= !before->hasValue();
                        before->set(value);
                    }
                    if (i < tiles.size() - 2) {
                        BineroTile* after = tiles[i + 2];
                        simplified |= !after->hasValue();
                        after->set(value);
                    }
                }

                // Avoid trios - compare the current value with the value two steps next
                if (i < tiles.size() - 2) {
                    BineroTile* twoNext = tiles[i + 2];
                    if (*current == *twoNext) {
                        int value = 1 - current->getValue();
                        simplified |= !next->hasValue();
                        next->set(value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Complete rows and columns
        if (zeros + ones < tiles.size()) {
            int halfSize = tiles.size() / 2;
            int maxKnown = std::max(zeros, ones);
            int value = zeros > ones ? 1 : 0;
            if (halfSize == maxKnown) {
                for (unsigned int i = 0; i < tiles.size(); i++) {
                    if (!tiles[i]->hasValue()) {
                        tiles[i]->set(value);
                        simplified = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (tiles.size() - zeros - ones != unknown) {
            unknown = tiles.size() - zeros - ones;
        }

        // Not implemented: Eliminate impossible combinations in this line
        // Not implemented: Eliminate impossible combinations based on completed rows and columns
        return simplified;
    }

};

class BineroMatchSet {
    std::vector<BineroMatch> matches;

public:
    BineroMatchSet(std::vector<BineroMatch> matches) : matches(matches) {
    }

    bool scan() {
        bool simplified = false;
        for (auto match : matches) {
            simplified |= match.scan();
        }
        return simplified;
    }
};


class BineroPuzzle {
public:
    int width;
    int height;
    std::vector<std::vector<BineroTile>> grid;
    std::vector<BineroMatchSet> match_sets;

    BineroPuzzle(int width, int height) : width(width), height(height) {
        std::vector<BineroMatch> rows;
        std::vector<BineroMatch> columns;

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            std::vector<BineroTile> a;
            std::vector<BineroTile*> rowPointers;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                BineroTile tile;
                a.push_back(tile);
            }
            grid.push_back(a);
        }

        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            std::vector<BineroTile*> columnTiles;
            for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
                BineroTile* tile = &grid[y][x];
                columnTiles.push_back(tile);
            }
            columns.push_back(BineroMatch(columnTiles));
        }

        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            std::vector<BineroTile*> rowTiles;
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                BineroTile* tile = &grid[y][x];
                rowTiles.push_back(tile);
            }
            rows.push_back(BineroMatch(rowTiles));
        }

        match_sets.push_back(BineroMatchSet(rows));
        match_sets.push_back(BineroMatchSet(columns));
    }

    void print() {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                std::cout << grid[y][x];
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }

    void clear() {
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
                grid[y][x].clear();
            }
        }
    }

    void set(int x, int y, int value) {
        grid[y][x].set(value);
    }

    void solve() {
        bool simplified = false;
        do {
            simplified = false;
            for (auto set : match_sets) {
                simplified |= set.scan();
            }
        }
        while (simplified);
    }

};

struct Puzzle {
public:
    BineroPuzzle puzzle;
    Puzzle() : puzzle(BineroPuzzle(4, 4)) {}
};

BineroPuzzle* readFromInput() {
    std::cout << "Enter Dimension: ";
    int size;
    std::cin >> size;
    BineroPuzzle* puzzle = new BineroPuzzle(size, size);

    for (int y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < size; x++) {
            char ch;
            std::cin >> ch;
            if (ch == '1') {
                puzzle->set(x, y, 1);
            }
            else if (ch == '0') {
                puzzle->set(x, y, 0);
            }
            else if (ch == 'x') {
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "Unknown char: " << ch;
            }
        }
    }
    return puzzle;
}

void readLine(BineroPuzzle* puzzle, const int y, const std::string line) {
    for (unsigned int x = 0; x < line.length(); x++) {
        char ch = line[x];
        if (ch == '1') {
            puzzle->set(x, y, 1);
        }
        else if (ch == '0') {
            puzzle->set(x, y, 0);
        }
    }
}

BineroPuzzle* readFromFile(const std::string fileName) {
    std::ifstream file;
    file.open(fileName);
    std::string line;
    if (file.is_open()) {
        getline(file, line);
        unsigned int size = line.length();
        BineroPuzzle* puzzle = new BineroPuzzle(size, size);
        readLine(puzzle, 0, line);
        for (unsigned int y = 1; y < size; y++) {
            getline(file, line);
            readLine(puzzle, y, line);
        }
        file.close();
        return puzzle;
    }
    file.close();
    BineroPuzzle* puzzle = new BineroPuzzle(1, 1);
    return puzzle;
}

int main() {
    //BineroPuzzle puzzle = readFromInput();
    BineroPuzzle* puzzle = readFromFile("puzzle.dat");

    puzzle->print();
    std::cin.get();
    std::cout << puzzle->width << " x " << puzzle->height << "\n";
    puzzle->solve();
    std::cout << "Solution:\n";
    puzzle->print();
    std::cin.get();
    delete puzzle;
    return 0;
}
```

Example puzzle.dat:

```
xxxx00
xxxxxx
x1xxxx
01x1xx
0xxx0x
xx1xxx
```

Primary questions:

- Am I making good usage of the operator functionalities of C++?
- Any other comments about the existing code welcome

I know I could have created a more user-friendly menu and such, instead of switching the commented line or changing file name. This code is not really meant to be *user-friendly*, but I hope it is *programmer-friendly*.

Comment: What do `BineroTile`, `BineroMatch`, `BineroMatchSet`, and `BineroPuzzle` translate into in English? My guess is `BinaryTile`, `BinaryMatch`, `BinaryMatchSet`, and `BinaryPuzzle`.

Comment: @RSahu The reason why I am calling them `Binero` is because when I first encountered this puzzle, it went by the name of "Binero". The term `Binary` is so much wider than `Binero`, I would rather name it `BinaryPuzzleTile`, `BinaryPuzzleMatch`... which I feel would be too long.

Answer (score 9):

I'll start with some of the basic conventions now.  There is quite a bit of code here.

- This looks unusual for a constructor:

  > ```
  > BineroTile() {
  >     clear();
  > }
  > ```

  The call to a function called `clear()` makes this look like a destructor, though that's not even what's being done here.

  If you're just trying to set initial values, use an initializer list:

  ```
  BineroTile()
      : zero(true)
      , one(true)
  {}
  ```
- This doesn't quite look right:

  > ```
  > int getValue() {
  >     if (!hasValue()) {
  >         return -1;
  >     }
  >     return one ? 1 : 0;
  >  }
  > ```

  What value is it getting?  It looks like it'll return a boolean value depending on the state of `one`.  Perhaps this should've been named something else.
- This `operator=` overload isn't in the proper form:

  > ```
  > void operator=(const int &value) {
  >     set(value);
  > }
  > ```

  You would typically use the argument as the right-hand operand to set the current *object* (`this`) to that operand.  You're not doing that at all here.

  Here's what it should look like:

  ```
  BineroTile& operator=(const BineroTile &rhs) {
      zero = rhs.zero;
      one = rhs.one;
      return *this;
  }
  ```

  In case you may need to check for self-assignment as well:

  ```
  if (this != &rhs) {
      zero = rhs.zero;
      one = rhs.one;
  }

  return *this;
  ```

  Moreover, you don't really have to overload `operator=` if you're just doing simple assignments.  The compiler automatically generates a default assignment operator for you.  One good reason to define your own `operator=` is if you have pointer members, which will *not* be handled properly automatically by the compiler.  This is because the compiler-generated version performs a [shallow copy instead of a deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy).
- `print()` should also be `const`.  This applies to all member functions, especially print functions, that don't modify any data members.  Any attempts at modifying data members within such functions will result in a compiler error.
- In `readFromFile()`, I don't think the last `close()` is needed if `file` fails to open.  This is usually only necessary for error-checking.
- Also in `readFromFile()`, there doesn't appear to be a need for `new`.  In C++, unlike in Java, manual memory allocation is used very sparingly in favor of the classes in the standard library that handle memory itself.  You are properly deallocating afterwards as you should, but again, it doesn't appear to be necessary here.

Comment: the `=` operator was to quickly assign the tile to an *int* value, your version of the operator doesn't even compile! (or else I am missing something significant in C++...) There's no such thing as `rhs.zero` when `rhs` is an `int`. `tile = 1` sets `tile.one = true; tile.zero = false;` So I'd say that I am using the argument as right-hand operand to set the current object...

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: You're right; I forgot to change something.  The argument type should be `BineroTile`.

Comment: I don't want to set a tile to the same value as another tile, I want to set the tile's properties to the values of an int! (Judging by your answer though, I guess that's not really the usual practice, huh?)

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: In that case, `operator=` is not needed for that.  Just a separate function will do.

Comment: I knew that it wasn't *needed*, I just wanted to use some of the features available to me in C++.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg, I find it very strange that you are justifying your decisions when a "thank you for your input" would be more appropriate.

Comment: @RSahu Sorry. You have a point. I do appreciate the input, I just want to make sure that Jamal understands my intentions correctly. I am not entirely clear if my usage of C++ operators would be considered 'abuse' or not. Is this usage of operators to 'assign an instance of a class to an int' this way considered abuse of C++ operators?

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: You can define an `operator=` or copy constructor to not copy each data member (unlike the default copy constructor), but it didn't look like you were doing that in yours.

Answer (score 9):

- You said

  > The entire grid should be filled up with 1's and 0's.

  That means the only state in `BineroTile` should be a `bool` - `true` for `1` and `false` for `0`. It's not clear why you need two `bool` members to capture `BineroTile`'s state. What does it mean when `one` is `true` and `zero` is `true`? What's the state of that tile?

  I am guessing that you want to capture "unspecified" as a state. In that case, an `enum` would be better.

  ```
  class BineroTile {
  public:
      enum State { UNSPECIFIED = -1, ZERO, ONE };
      State state;

      // ... 
  };
  ```
- The `operator=` function

  Idiomatically speaking, it's perfectly reasonable to use:

  ```
  BineroTile tile;
  tile = 1;
  ```

  However, the signature of the function and the implementation need to be updated to be idiomatic:

  ```
  BineroTile& operator=(const int &value) {
      set(value);
      return *this;
  }
  ```

  Then, you can use:

  ```
  BineroTile tile1;
  BineroTile tile2;
  tile1 = tile2 = 1;
  ```
- Redundant data in `BineroPuzzle`

  `width` and `height` are redundant member variables. Please remove them. You can get them from the `grid` member variable.
- Better initialization of `BineroPuzzle::grid`

  You can use

  ```
  BineroPuzzle(int width, int height) :
  grid(height, std::vector<BineroPuzzle>(width, BineroTile())) {
  ```

  to initialize `grid`. That will remove a block of code from `BineroPuzzle`'s constructor.

Comment: An `enum` definitely makes sense here. It is true that I want to capture the `unspecified` state. Both zero and one should not be true at the same time. About that `tile1 = tile2 = 1;` , if I understand that correctly, then `tile1` and `tile2` will refer to the same object after that assignment? (Unless I also implement the `operator=` that Jamal suggested?)

Comment: No, `tile1` and `tile2` will continue to be different objects. Their states will be identical.

Answer (score 6):

I see some things that I think could help you improve your code.

### Separate interface from implementation

It makes the code somewhat longer for a code review, but it's often very useful to separate the interface from the implementation.  In C++, this is usually done by putting the interface into separate `.h` files and the corresponding implementation into `.cpp` files.  It helps users (or reviewers) of the code see and understand the interface and hides implementation details.

### Make data members `private`

The `zero` and `one` members of `BineroTile` are public but they really ought to be private members.  Similarly, data members for `BineroPuzzle` should be made private.  If you need accessors, you could use simple `const` ones like this:

```
int Width() const { return width; }
int Height() const { return height; }
```

### Use `const` where practical

The `hasValue` and `getValue` member functions of `BineroTile` do not alter the underlying object and therefore should be declared `const`.

### Isolate platform-specific code

If you must have `stdafx.h`, consider wrapping it so that the code is portable:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS
#include "stdafx.h"
#endif
```

### Avoid reusing the same name for different things

Inside your `BinaroPuzzle::solve()` function, you use a variable `set` for each `match_set`, but there is also a member function `set`.  Although it's unambiguous to the compiler, it could be clearer to a reader of the code if that variable were named something else.

### Don't rely on uninitialized variables

In side the `BinerorMatch::scan` function, we have this peculiar code:

```
if (tiles.size() - zeros - ones != unknown) {
    unknown = tiles.size() - zeros - ones;
}
```

The first problem is that `unknown` is, well, unknown at that point the first time through the code, so your code is making a decision based on an uninitialized value which is an error.  It works anyway because `unknown` is then set to a particular value.  Why not just set the value?

```
unknown = tiles.size() - zeros - ones;
```

### Prefer references to raw pointers

Within `BineroMatch::scan()`, variables `current`, `next`, `before` and `after` are all declared and used as pointers to `BinaroTile` but what you really want is a reference.  The difference is that a reference cannot be `nullptr` and must actually point to an object, which is exactly the guarantee your code relies on anyway.
Instead, I would do it like this:

```
BineroTile& current = *tiles[i];

if (current.getValue() == 0) {
    zeros++;
}
// etc.
```

### Make your functions match typical usage

Every instance of use of `hasValue()` negates the result to use it.  That strongly suggests that the function should probably be this instead:

```
bool isUnknown() const {
    return zero == one;
}
```

Similarly, the code includes this:

```
if (current->getValue() == 0) {
    zeros++;
}
if (current->getValue() == 1) {
    ones++;
}
```

I would instead be inclined to write that as:

```
if (current->hasValue()) {
    if (current->isZero()) {
        ++zeroes;
    } else {
        ++ones;
    }
}
```

### Use an idiomatic `operator=`

Your current `BineroTile::operator=()` is this:

```
void operator=(const int &value) {
    set(value);
}
```

It should actually return `BineroTile&` and not `void`, otherwise chained operations such as `a = b = c` can't work.  Since the result of this is just a simple copy, delete the whole function and let the compiler automatically generate it.  However, you might want to create another form, like this:

```
BineroTile &operator=(bool value) {
    one = value;
    zero = !value;
    return *this;
}
```

### Provide for more natural syntax

Rather than the somewhat strange thing that's being done with `value` inside `BineroMatch::scan()`, you might want to use the suggested `operator=` above and this:

```
bool operator!() const {
    return zero;
}
```

That will allow you write much more clearly, as with this example:

```
if (i > 0) {
    BineroTile& before = *tiles[i - 1];
    simplified |= before.isUnknown();
    before = !current;
}
```

### Eliminate unused structures and classes

The `Puzzle` struct is unused and should be deleted.

### Separate input from output

The `BineroPuzzle::readFromInput()` both prompts and reads.  Better design would be to separate prompts from the actual input.  Alternatively, since it's unused in this sample program, you could omit it.

### Reconsider your choice of data structures

The code currently uses a number of `std::vectors` for things that might be better expressed as `std::valarray`.  Using a `std::valarray` would allow you to use a [`std::slice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/slice) which seems like a better fit for this particular problem.

### Prefer constructors to special member functions

The `readFromFile` function has two problems, as I see it.  First, it's a free-standing function and not a member function even though it's clearly closely associated with the `BineroPuzzle` class.  Second, it returns a raw pointer rather than an actual object.  Finally, the use of `new` and `delete` is really not needed here, especially since the value returned is never checked for `nullptr`.  You can solve all of those problems by refactoring this as a constructor taking `std::ifstream&` as an input.

```
BineroPuzzle::BineroPuzzle(std::istream &file) {
    std::string line;
    getline(file, line);
    unsigned int size = line.length();
    BineroPuzzle puzzle(size, size);
    readLine(&puzzle, 0, line);
    for (unsigned int y = 1; y < size; y++) {
        getline(file, line);
        readLine(&puzzle, y, line);
    }
    std::swap(*this, puzzle);
}
```

This could (and should!) be refactored further, including making `readLine` a private member function but I'll leave that to you.

### Prefer a stream inserter to a custom `print` routine

Your custom `BineroPuzzle::print` routine could instead be written as a stream inserter:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &out, const BineroPuzzle &bp) {
    for (int y = 0; y < bp.Height(); y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < bp.Width(); x++) {
            out << bp.grid[y][x];
        }
        out << "\n";
    }
    return out;
}
```

### Prefer `for` to `do ... while`

In `BinaroPuzzle::solve()` the loop is this:

```
void solve() {
    bool simplified = false;
    do {
        simplified = false;
        for (auto set : match_sets) {
            simplified |= set.scan();
        }
    }
    while (simplified);
}
```

A clearer alternative would be this:

```
void solve() {
    for (bool simplified = true; simplified; ) {
        simplified = false;
        for (auto set : match_sets) {
            simplified |= set.scan();
        }
    }
}
```

Or you could also use `std::for_each` and a lambda:

```
void solve() {
    for (bool simplified = true; simplified; ) {
        simplified = false;
        std::for_each(match_sets.begin(), match_sets.end(), 
                [&simplified](BineroMatchSet &bms){ 
                    return simplified |= bms.scan(); 
                }
        );
    }
}
```

### Omit `return 0`

When a C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no reason to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.